# How to sort through array and wrap each with HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JSON looks like this:

```
[{"title":"Modern\/Contemporary House of mine.","link":"http:\/\/buildworx-mc.com\/forum\/showthread.php?tid=1718","images":["http:\/\/i1139.photobucket.com\/albums\/n555\/xDJBOUTIx\/house1.png","http:\/\/i1139.photobucket.com\/albums\/n555\/xDJBOUTIx\/House2.png","http:\/\/i1139.photobucket.com\/albums\/n555\/xDJBOUTIx\/House3.png","http:\/\/i1139.photobucket.com\/albums\/n555\/xDJBOUTIx\/House4.png","http:\/\/i1139.photobucket.com\/albums\/n555\/xDJBOUTIx\/House5.png","http:\/\/i1139.photobucket.com\/albums\/n555\/xDJBOUTIx\/House6.png"]}
```

I can get the title and the link just fine. But I can't get the images because in some there are multiple links.

[image]

I'm trying to get each images link to be wrapped in HTML.

```
$.getJSON("gallery/getScreenshots.php", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, image) {
      var link = image.link, title = image.title. images = image.images;

    $img = $('<img>').attr('src', images);
    $('#screenshots').append($img);

   });
```

But the outcome is this:

```
<img src="http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/house1.png,http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House2.png,http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House3.png,http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House4.png,http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House5.png,http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House6.png" alt="">
```

How can I sort through the array and get each image to append into `<img>?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `$.each` loop:

```
$.each(images, function(i,el) {
    $('#screenshots').append($('<img>',{'src',el}));
});
```

Comment: I used yours and I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Answer (score 0):

Hell Trippy,

This is the code below and working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/cgbHG/1/).

```
var info=[
    {
        "title": "Modern/Contemporary House of mine.",
        "link": "http://buildworx-mc.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=1718",
        "images": [
            "http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/house1.png",
            "http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House2.png",
            "http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House3.png",
            "http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House4.png",
            "http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House5.png",
            "http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n555/xDJBOUTIx/House6.png"
        ]
    }
];
var album=info[0]["images"];
for(i=0;i<album.length;i++)
{  console.log(album[i]);
  $('#screenshots').append($('<img>').attr('src', album[i])                                    
                      .css({'width':'200px','height':200px'}));
}
```

​